# How do I properly return a string from an unmanaged third-party dll to C#?

Tags: c#, string, dll, pinvoke

So, background information: I'm trying to issue commands to an external device (namely, an impedance analyzer, the AIM 4170D) and have been given a dll to provide the command interface between C# code and the device itself. I don't have the code for the dll. Admittedly, I don't even know what language the dll was written in. The names of the commands themselves as well as the arguments were given by documentation that came with the dll. The documentation also states that the string will never exceed 255 bytes in length.

I've consistently gotten the error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." when attempting to retrieve a string from the dll. I'll admit this is an assumption, but the two dll commands that I can run before having run AIM_GetVersion, both of which return ints, have worked fine (not only returning no errors, but retrieving a response from the device). What I've read so far suggests that working with strings from dlls can be problematic, but also assumes I have access to the dlls original code to address the issue.

First attempt:

```
[DllImport(@"AIM_863_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern string AIM_GetVersion(int flag);

string ver = AIM_GetVersion(1);
```

Second attempt:

```
[DllImport(@"AIM_863_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr AIM_GetVersion(int flag);

IntPtr ver = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(255);
ver = AIM_GetVersion(1);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ver);
```

Both attempts got the same error (as above) upon calling AIM_GetVersion. If I try to run the second set while the device is off, I get the error "Invalid access to memory location." at FreeHGlobal. (Okay, I did try more than two things, but the "second" attempt was the only one I found that caused a change in the program's behavior. I provided it here in the case that it could narrow what the issue could be.)

Also, I'm compiling it using VS2010 using x86.

Thank you for any help you can provide. Also, I'm kinda new at this, so if I've left anything out that could be helpful, I'll provide it if possible.

Edit:
Okay, I'm adding all of the relevant code to this function that I got from the third party here. At the top of the code is simply listed:

```
EXPORT  AIM_GetVersion
```

And further on, the actual function (which just calls another function deeper within the dll I wasn't given):

```
' External command for DLL:
SUB AIM_GetVersion(flag:int),string
extcmnd=1
runmode=1
Get_Version(0)

extcmnd=0
if error : s1="34506" : endif
RETURN s1
EndSub
```

If I need more information, I can ask the company again, but I'm not really sure what else to ask for.

Comment: We've no idea what the signature of the unmanaged function is. Please let us know that. Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: Although I can say that both your C# attempts are wrong. I just can't tell you what is right until I know for sure what the unmanaged function is.

Comment: Okay, I added additional information as an edit to the main post.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. You need to be precise. Example C++ calling code would suffice. And the declaration in the header file. It's likely that Hans' answer is what you need to do but you really should be clear on what you are doing. If you don't know C or C++ then you have some learning to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your Marshal.AllocHGlobal() call just leaks memory, delete that.  You can't call Marshal.FreeHGlobal(), the odds that the string was allocated on the process heap are miniscule.  C code like this usually returns a literal string, it should not and can't be released.

Just call Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to convert the IntPtr to a string, nothing else.  Write a little test program that does this a billion times, you'll feel much better when it doesn't explode.

Comment: I did as you suggested. When the device is off, I get the correct error code    from the dll. However, when it is on I still get the "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." error.

Comment: I cannot possibly guess how a string turned into an error code.  Contact the DLL owner for support.